# NSMenuItem not responding to setIndentationLevel:

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

If I call `setIndentationLevel:` on an NSMenuItem then nothing happens, if I call `indentationLevel` on it after I set it to 3, it returns 3 like it should. I'm adding the menu items to the Dock menu and I don't see anything changing.

```
NSMenuItem *menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"title" action: nil keyEquivalent: @""];
[menuItem setIndentationLevel: 3];
[dockMenu addItem: menuItem];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be because you can't customize dock menu Items like that, but I am not sure. Maybe you should try to do this all in IB?

Comment: That does indeed seems to be the case. I could get it to work with a normal menu. But not with an IB dock menu or a programatically created dock menu. iTunes seems to have it working though.

Comment: That may be because iTunes is a Carbon App.